# How to show total rate in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I need item wise total amount from below table (quired data) in SQL.
How to achieve this? please suggest me-
NB: Please see the attached file, I am unable to paste it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(totalamount) over (partition by itemid) as totalamountsum
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward - Just use a subquery and sum the value :

```
SELECT t1.*,
(Select SUM(t1.TotalAmount) from myTable where ItemID=t1.ITEMID) as TotalAmountSum
from myTable t1;
```